# Read/get the current value of an object in Project VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

I'm struggling to save the current value of an object (at least I think it's an object) in MS Project VBA.

Here's what I'm trying to do, save the value of my current header text.

```
dim a As String (or Variant/Object?)
a = Application.FilePageSetupHeader.Text.Value
```

This obviously doesn't work, but gets the point across.
The syntax for this is:

```
expression. FilePageSetupHeader( ** Name, ** Alignment, ** Text** )
```

with Name and Text being passed as a string.

If I get this to work, I'll also be interested in extracting the `NormalType` value from this object. Notice I'll have to specify the item:

```
GridlinesEditEx Item:=4, NormalType:=1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there an object browser you can use to explore? They appear to be methods you apply via Application. but I don't know if you have a specific object to which you  apply result. It would then be that object you would query (like PageSetUp...) to examine the set parameter values.

Comment: Yes there's an object browser that I've checked out. I'd just like to store the Text string inside the method as a string to roll back to after my sub is complete. But reading Rachels reply it seems methods are write-only....

Comment: Well Rachel's answer is the one I was going to give until I was playing around with instances in Excel where I could use an Application object method to assign a value to another object e.g. PageSetUp and access the set paramaters from that object. I don't have Project so couldn't test if anything similar was possible. I found a sad lack of online info around the read/write properties in relation to Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilePageSetupHeader` is a ***method*** of the application object, not a ***property*** ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-filepagesetupheader-method-project)). The MS Project object model does not have a header object to interrogate, so unfortunately the headers (and footers) are write-only.

Comment: probably worth adding the other method as well.

Comment: Thanks for the sad news. I have seen the word "method" written on MSDN, but I haven't understood that they are write-only. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: And to clarify further, it's not so much that methods are write-only as that methods *do* something where as properties store information.

Comment: @QHarr it's not just headers and footers; there are 10+ methods that relate to page setup. Bottom line, unlike Excel or Word, Project doesn't have (or at least doesn't expose) a page setup object.

Comment: @RachelHettinger Thanks. That was what I couldn't test as I don't have Project. I was surprised there was no easy resource I could find to explore the object model of Project online.